# I am not sure where or how to post a question about writing a program that uses some of my hardware's features

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, site-recommendation

I am looking for a way to decode and encode videos on Linux using the hardware acceleration features my system offers. Yesterday I posted this question, but it was closed: [Decode and encode videos using hardware accelleration in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403709/decode-and-encode-videos-using-hardware-accelleration-in-linux). I am not sure why it breaks the guidelines. The message says:

> We do not allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. You can edit the question or post a new one.

Is it because of the way I phrased the question or is Stack Overflow the wrong board for the help I need?

How can I modify the question and/or where should I post it on?

Comment: That question is way too broad. For starters (but that would salvage your question) in what language do you expect that example code to be? Haskell? Python? Algol?

Comment: @rene: anything is fine. If it is easier to get an answer for some languages rather than others I am happy to use those languages... If I really have to pick one, I would pick C so that I have more understanding and control on the API. Or whatever other language the hardware-accellerated video processing APIs are written natively in.

Comment: "Is there any example piece of code I can download" is definitely asking for a off-site resource. I'm not sure you can reformulate you question in any way that would fit SO. What you basically need is a good tutorial, but that is something SO can't provide. If you have started with your application and need help with a specific problem while implementing, then go ahead and ask here.

Comment: @BDL: I literally have no idea where to start. I have been looking for this on Google for hours but could not find anything. A tutorial would be awesome, but it does not seem to exist. I am happy with receiving a list of function/system-call names so that I can look up their doc, or any other hint on how to write a program that decodes a video in hardware. There is no way to ask on StackOverflow or any other StackExchange board how to do this?

Comment: @Helloer: No, there is no way to asks such questions on SO or any other SE board. Maybe reddit or some other internet community may help you, but on SO you have to ask a single specific question.

Comment: @BDL: I find a lot of questions on this website, especially older ones, that are extremely vague. This rule do not apply to them because they are old enough, because moderators arbitrarily decided they can stay, or what other reasons?

Comment: @Helloer: because community moderation isn't perfect and because we have learned, over time, what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: can you link to some resources to understand how StackOverflow was improved by stricter rules? Most of the times google lands me on many-years-old posts that break the current guidelines, but have millions of views and thousands of votes. Without evidence I struggle at believing your claim that those posts did not work. And why do not those posts get closed, anyways?

Comment: @Helloer I only have 50 close votes to spend each day and the many new bad questions that come in every day take up all votes. There are not enough close voters, yet there are plenty of  new users that post new off-topic/ broad / unanswerable questions.

Comment: @Helloer: no, I'm not going to do that at this time, sorry. The discussions have all taken place either here on this Meta, or on the [central Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com), which was, once upon a time, the Meta site for Stack Overflow before it was set up to be separate.

Comment: Attitudes such as "anything is fine" are huge red flags to using [so]. It is highly unlikely that "anything is fine", because that would mean the asker has already mastered a breadth of languages and topics – in which case they would not be asking the question. So likely they do not care because they do not expect to do any work with it themselves, or they do not care *yet* because they have no idea how much work this actually is. Either way means a lot of time will be wasted by the volunteers on [so] to do the work the asker should have done.

Comment: @Helloer: And please don't conflate popularity with suitability. Views and votes are not the only criteria when it comes to something working here and being on topic. The 'programmer jokes' post was hugely popular, got tons of votes, and was an unmitigated disaster, for example.

Comment: You can over [meta-tag:scope], that should give you enough content and links to spend the next 6 to 8 weeks on.

Comment: I bet that a lot of people reach this site through those questions though. And those questions apparently offer a terrible example and set the wrong expectations. You should seriously consider deleting them in order to reduce the amount of new bad questions that come in every day.

Comment: Not sure which *You* you mean but if that is the community you are now part of, then yes, we agree. I slacked off a bit as I was answering questions on Meta.

Comment: It was a plural "you". The StackOverflow moderation team or community might want that. Maybe I could bring up this point in a different post (maybe on MetaStackExchange).

Comment: @Helloer 100% with you. When do you pick up a mop and bucket to help clean up? Cause you're aware your general attitude of 'any language is fine, just gimme something to download' is.... Well not helping *at all* change that perception? Only a handful of ppl moderate while others don't care and just want their answer.

Comment: There are plenty of people who want to remove those old questions, and have voted to do so. There are plenty of people, however, who feel that those old questions should be kept around (for various reasons I'm sure they'd be happy to expound on). But that's neither here nor there. The current moderation policy is spelled out in the [help].

Comment: @Patrice: I'm happy to help, but I cannot close or delete posts. Should I flag those questions when I run into them or report them somewhere?

Comment: @Helloer yes, you should flag. They go then into a review queue where users with close privileges will deal with it.

Comment: Basically, although the site's rules have changed over the years with experience on what works and what doesn't, we don't want to destroy value by deleting old questions that would no longer be accepted here today. So, we keep them. But we do expect you to follow the *current* rules, because those rules work. Trust us when we say that the old, highly-ranked questions you find are *rare exceptions*, not the norm. Do feel free to flag them, and we'll still close them, but, as Heretic Monkey said, there are many of us who'd prefer not to delete them if they still might have some value to someone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is Stack Overflow the wrong board for the help I need?

Yes, SO and basically all of the SE network is the wrong venue to get *help* for what you need.

We expect an actual question with a specific problem that is focused enough to be answerable in a few paragraphs.

Your example questions is way off from that base rule. Which programming language are you using, what compiler are you using. What type of input formats you have ready to experiment with? Why doesn't any of the available hello worlds and/or guidance available, for example:

- https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/enabling-high-performance-video-encoding-decoding-and-preprocessing.html
- https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp
- http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/11/MediaSDK_User_Guide_1_1_Beta.pdf
- https://vdpau.pages.freedesktop.org/libvdpau/
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=VDPAU&mixed=0
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22VA-API%22&mixed=0

doesn't help you to get started?

You could take the C/C++ code from a vendor specific SDK, try to implement to decoding part, have a look at the source of FFMpeg to get an idea how hardware virtualization works, re-implement that in your attempt and then ask a specific question about that code. That will be useful for others. Hardware acceleration with decoding and encoding is simply too much in one take. No one is going to write a book for you on that.

In general, we're not an awesome place to find a tutorial or get coached / tutored into (complex) subjects you're new to.

You need to get started first by other means: tutorials, examples, courses. And we're not a replacement for Googling or Binging, we think users are able to cater for their own specific needs and "answers" to those need are not likely to be valuable for future visitors, even if the advice isn't gone stale after 6 to 8 weeks.

If you insist on getting help here, this is what you can do:

- Write a minimal code example that only decodes a video on your Linux flavor
- Explain/prove that it doesn't use Hardware Acceleration
- Show how that hardware acceleration is achieved with a vendor specific Windows API / SDK
- Ask how to do the same for the Linux version of your code.

If that question doesn't get downvoted but answered then you can rinse repeat that process for the encoding part. In the end you have your tutorial by means of small steps. The answers to the several question have lasting value for many visitors long after you have moved on.

See also: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: The "available hello worlds ansd/or guidance available" you linked says: "Supported Operating Systems = • Microsoft Windows Vista* (32- and 64-bit versions) • Microsoft Windows* 7 (32- and 64-bit versions)". My only requirement, stressed both in the title and in the post, is that I need it for Linux. Any programming language is fine. Any compiler or interpreter is fine. Any video format or encoding is fine.

Comment: After the edit: the second link you posted in for NVIDIA only cards. I stressed in my question that I have an AMD CPU and GPU and would prefer to find a solution that is not vendor-specific.

Comment: After the second edit: the third link, specific for AMD (from 2014 and probably no longer relevant) says in Chapter 2.1 "Prerequisites" that it's for Windows only.

Comment: If you don't want to get started, then no advice can help you. Maybe stepping back to windows first and then move to linux can help if all example / sdks are Windows only.

Comment: How is a Windows-only framework ever gonna help me at all with my goal of using hardware video accelleration on Linux? Even if I master it, what do I do with the expertise I gained, if what my expertise is based on does not exist on other platforms? First you say I should pick one language, compiler and input format and then offer links for hardware and operating systems I do not have and am not interested in...

Comment: After the latest edit: OK, thanks for the advices. I'll try to do what you suggested.

Comment: @Helloer I have spent 10 seconds googling for stuff. You have spent hours on it, yet you haven't included any of what you looked at already in your SO question. Even if you had your question should not be answered but it at least it would have relieved me from trying to convey that your research and the result of it is your responsibility, not mine. I don't have the urge to decode / encode stuff on Linux, I can't even remember th last time I compiled stuff on a Linux box, let alone wrote a C program.

Comment: I never expect you to find something better, nor to search for it. In hours of research I found the links you shared and many, many others, but nothing useful enough. What I was hoping for, by asking the original question, was to find someone who has experience in the field and could have shared few insight or links to obscure resources that could have opened my way.

Comment: @Helloer: and folks have been spending time and energy trying to help you on meta, telling repeatedly that using the site to try to get an experienced person to point you in the right direction is not what this site is for. Please believe believe that they are 1) telling you the truth and 2) are giving you this information in the spirit of helping you use this site in the best way possible.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter: I understand that. I am grateful for the time rene spent answering. I accepted this answer and kept the conversation polite. Nevertheless I feel some general hostility from the community. As an example, what is so wrong in this meta question to deserve -9 points and growing?

Comment: @Helloer it certainly could attract downvotes for lack of research as [this search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=seeking+recommendations+for+books%2C+tools%2C+software+libraries) returns a bunch of posts that could at least have answered *I am not sure why it breaks the guidelines.*. Also on Meta prior research and including what you found and concluded is kind of expected.